# AC ground wire to neutral

Tags: electrical, hvac

Help me understand what is going on. My HVAC has the ground wire grounded to the side of the unit. On the main house breaker panel however the grounding wire is connected to the Neutral side and not the grounding side. Is that a mistake?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @timi2shoes -- can you post a photo of your electric meter box? something funky is going on with your electrical install and I don't like it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an answer to the original, general question about ground vs. neutral. But now seeing pictures of your actual panel:

- THIS IS **NOT** YOUR MAIN PANEL!

You have a 4-wire feed from the top - hot, hot, neutral, ground. That is normal for a subpanel, not for a main panel. In addition, you have no main breaker, which is needed in a main panel (exception: Rule of 6 panel, but this doesn't look like one to me).

Which means that your actual main panel is the panel that has the other end of the feed to this panel. Most likely that is a "Meter Main" which is basically a big box that has both the meter and a main panel with a main breaker. Which means:

- You need to move all grounds from the neutral bar (right) to the ground bar (left)

There are plenty of empty ground screws on the left. In addition, with most panels you can put 2 or sometimes even 3 ground wires in one ground screw, subject to wire size and panel label instructions.

Note however that while I see definitely one and possibly a second "normal" ground wires, the twisted stranded split into 4 (upper batch) or 3 (lower batch) copper wires may actually be neutrals for a couple of the larger circuits. One of those looks like it actually has white insulation (just cut back a couple of inches) and the other one is not clear. If those are *actually neutrals* then (a) they should be wrapped up with white electrical tape because large amounts of bare wire means easy contact to the case which would connect them to ground and (b) each entire wire bundle should be under a single neutral screw. If the wire really won't fit (the panel label should tell you what sizes are allowed) then you can usually get lugs designed to fit into the neutral bar to connect larger wires.

In addition:

- No low-voltage inside the panel

There appears to be a transformer, probably for HVAC or doorbell, sitting in the bottom of the panel. That should be mounted on a knockout of the panel or in/on a separate box outside the panel. The way it is sitting in the panel, the low-voltage wires are inside the panel, which is not allowed.

---

It is perfectly fine and normal.

In the US electrical system, ground and neutral are connected in one place in each building - the main panel. In the main panel, there is usually a screw or jumper that connects the neutral bar to the panel case. Any ground bars are always connected to the panel case. In the main panel *only*, ground wires from individual circuits can be placed on ground bars *or* on neutral bars. Neutral wires always go only on the neutral bar.

In any subpanels (e.g., an extra panel in another part of the house, or sometimes what *seems* to be the main panel is technically a subpanel and the *real* main panel is a "Meter Main" outside), ground wires go *only* on ground bars, neutral wires on neutral bars and there is **no connection between the neutral bar and the panel case or ground**.

As ground wires make their way to devices, a few things can happen:

- If you have metal boxes, the ground connects to the metal box. With metal conduit, the ground may be the metal conduit itself. If there is a ground wire (green or bare) it connects to the metal box with a screw.
- If you have plastic boxes, all ground wires are connected together, as well as to any devices (receptacles, switches, etc.)
- With metal boxes, switches with metal yokes are automagically grounded - no need to connect anything to a ground screw on the switch, but if the switch includes a ground wire then it should be attached to the box.
- With metal boxes, *self-grounding* receptacles work just like switches.
- On most devices with metal cases - washer, dryer, light fixtures, HVAC equipment, etc. - the ground wire is bonded to the metal case.

There is one very important exception that you need to be aware of. In ye olden times, receptacles for dryers and for some ovens/ranges (if not hardwired) did not have a ground pin. For compatibility reasons, this continued to be allowed for decades, and even now many dryers and ovens/ranges include instructions for 3-wire and 4-wire connections. The 3-wire connections have turned out be **dangerous** in certain circumstances because they bond ground to neutral *in the appliance*. This is generally easy to fix by removing the bond (easy) and replacing the 3-wire receptacle (usually NEMA 10-30) with a 4-wire grounded receptacle (usually NEMA 14-30). Unfortunately, many people get a dryer with a 3-wire cord/plug and change the receptacle to 3-wire instead of changing the dryer to 4-wire, and the problem persists - and it can be a *deadly* problem.

Comment: I have doubts that the left bar is actually ground. It's isolated from the box, (mounted on plastic) which *generally* means it's subtly bonded to the right bar, (can't see the crossovers with the breakers in place) which either means this is from the before-times when 3-wire feeds were OK (even though they used 4) or that one of the regular electricians will know it's so, or that this one is somehow different than most and they are not bonded.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I see what you are saying. *However*, except for the two messes that are, I think, 100A neutral wires butchered to fit multiple screws, and 1 or 2 real grounds on the neutral, everything else is clearly split ground on left and neutral on right. Plus there is no main breaker. So I'm betting on that really being a ground bar on the left, despite it being in the bus bar plastic holder rather than just attached directly to the case.

Comment: The feed wire connecting to the left bar has no insulation, while the feed wire connecting to the right bar is insulated - I would agree that the left is ground and the right is neutral.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!